# Upgrading Python on RHEL 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, rhel, rhel7

***TL;DR How do I get Python 2.7.9+ on RHEL 7?***

I'm using Ansible for configuration management of a RHEL 7 server. I've run into a number of cases where an Ansible module (or whatever action it was trying to perform) requires Python 2.7.9+, but RHEL 7 (tested on 7.1 and 7.3) only come with Python 2.7.5. I see a few options:

- **Installing through a different package repository.** I was looking around for an easy way to upgrade though `yum`, but couldn't find one. Is there a repository that has Python 2.7.9+?

  - Sub-question: Is there a site to search for a given version of a given package, and then find out what repository(s) it exists in?
- **Installing Python 2.7.9+ from source.** I tried to do this, but I apparently couldn't get the compilation to pick up system libraries like zlib, so a bunch of the Ansible modules ended up failing when using it as the `ansible_python_interpreter`. Possible that I could spend more time and get that working.
- **Use Python 3.** Ansible has [experimental Python 3 support](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/python_3_support.html), but I'm worried about the unknown stability of this.

Any advice on the easiest path forward? I'm relatively new to system administration, so very possible there's a straightforward solution I'm missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel. There are plenty of Anisble roles to do this.

[MiniConda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html) quick-install will install Python (+ Anaconda, but without all the dependencies) with one shell script.

Currently, I have used [this Ansible role](https://github.com/andrewrothstein/ansible-miniconda), and it is running great on RHEL 6 & 7. If you pass the `miniconda_make_sys_default = true` variable to the role, it updates the `PATH` accordingly.

---

Sidenote: If you are talking about the host machine and not the machines you are provisioning, miniconda works there too.

Comment: Yep, I mean the remote machines. Will give this a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat Software Collections provides newer Python versions that don't mess with the original. The 2.7 version is up to 2.7.8.  See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/2.2_Release_Notes/chap-RHSCL.html#sect-RHSCL-Changes

and

https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/get-started/